Typical Optical Thickness for Ice and Liquid Water Clouds Over Central Southern Africa
I am developing a cloud opacity index for use in climate modeling and need guidance on the typical optical thickness values for liquid water and ice water clouds over central southern Africa (land regions). This ratio will be used to weight ERA5’s ice and liquid water cloud datasets.
Challenges:
Cloud physics literature provides global averages but lacks region-specific values for the tropics or subtropics over land.
Questions:

Are there established optical thickness values for liquid and ice water clouds over tropical/subtropical land, particularly in central southern Africa?
Could you recommend datasets or methods to empirically derive this ratio?

Objective:
The goal is to use this weighted opacity index as a proxy for cloud radiative effects in regional climate analysis. Any insights into appropriate data sources, methodologies, or regional studies would be appreciated.

I'd recon the relation between cloud thickness or water content and the opacity is globally the same. Possibly you can get cloud data on height and water content from weather forecast, especially those geared towards aviation. What grounds do you have that the opacity of water should be region-specific?
